# Add rows dynamically to Visual Force

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a custom object that will hold data like column, operator and values. The user interface will allow a user to build a sql query online. The user can then Add/Delete conditions. I have an extension that has a Save method. I have a debug statement in my save condition. I am unable to invoke this method. Can someone please help?

My apex page is as follows:

```
    <apex:pageblock id="pb1">

    <apex:repeat value="{!lstInner}" var="e1" id="therepeat">
            <apex:panelGrid columns="5">

            <apex:panelGrid headerClass="Name">
                <apex:facet name="header">Del</apex:facet>
                <apex:commandButton value="X" action="{!Del}" rerender="pb1">
                    <apex:param name="rowToBeDeleted" value="{!e1.recCount}" assignTo="{!selectedRowIndex}"></apex:param>
                </apex:commandButton>
            </apex:panelGrid>   

            <apex:panelGrid title="SPD" >
                <apex:facet name="header">Condition</apex:facet> 
                      <apex:selectList value="{!e1.acct.Condition__c}" multiselect="false" size="1">
                            <apex:selectOptions value="{!conditions}"/>
                      </apex:selectList>                                                                         
            </apex:panelGrid>


            <apex:panelGrid >
                <apex:facet name="header">Field</apex:facet>                    
                 <apex:selectList value="{!e1.acct.Field__c}" multiselect="false" size="1">
                            <apex:selectOptions value="{!items}"/>
                      </apex:selectList>            
            </apex:panelGrid>

            <apex:panelGrid >
                <apex:facet name="header">Comparison</apex:facet>
                <apex:selectList value="{!e1.acct.Comparison__c}" multiselect="false" size="1">
                            <apex:selectOptions value="{!comparisons}"/>
                </apex:selectList>                       
            </apex:panelGrid> 

            <apex:panelGrid >
                <apex:facet name="header">Value</apex:facet>
                <apex:inputfield value="{!e1.acct.Value__c}"/>
            </apex:panelGrid>                               

        </apex:panelgrid>
    </apex:repeat>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

```
public with sharing class MultiAdd
{

public Map <String, Schema.SObjectType> schemaMap = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
public String selectedObject {get; set;}
public String selectedField {get; set;}    
public String inputValue{get; set;}
public String selectedCondition{get; set;}
public String selectedComparison{get; set;}

public SelectOption[] conditionOptions { //this is where we're going to pull the list
    public get;
    private set;
}

public SelectOption[] comparisonOptions { //this is where we're going to pull the list
    public get;
    private set;
}

public List<SelectOption> getConditions() 
{
        List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
        String[] conditions= new String[]{'AND','OR','NOT'};
        for (String c: conditions) 
        {
           options.add( new SelectOption(c,c));
           }
        return options;
}

public List<SelectOption> getComparisons() 
{
        List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
        String[] comparisons= new String[]{'equals','not equal','greater than','less than','greater than or equal','less than or equal','starts with'}; 
        for (String c: comparisons) 
        {
           options.add( new SelectOption(c,c));
           }
        return options;
}


public List<SelectOption> getItems() {

        List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
        //options.add(new SelectOption('US','US'));
        //options.add(new SelectOption('CANADA','Canada'));
        //options.add(new SelectOption('MEXICO','Mexico'));
        List<Schema.SObjectField> optionsList = Schema.SObjectType.Contact.fields.getMap().values();
        for( SObjectField s : optionsList )
        {
            options.add( new SelectOption(s.getDescribe().getLabel(), s.getDescribe().getLabel()) );
        }

        return options;
    }

public List<SelectOption> getObjectFields() 
 {
        Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> schemaMap = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
        Schema.SObjectType ObjectSchema = schemaMap.get(selectedObject);
        Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldMap = ObjectSchema.getDescribe().fields.getMap();
        List<SelectOption> fieldNames = new List<SelectOption>();
        for (String fieldName: fieldMap.keySet()) 
        {  
            fieldNames.add(new SelectOption(fieldName,fieldName));
          //fieldMap.get(fieldName).getDescribe().getLabel();//It provides to get the object fields label.
        }
        return fieldNames;
  }                 






//will hold the SOQLQuery__c records to be saved
public List<SOQLQuery__c>lstAcct  = new List<SOQLQuery__c>();

//list of the inner class
public List<innerClass> lstInner 
{   get;set;    }

//will indicate the row to be deleted
public String selectedRowIndex
{get;set;}  

//no. of rows added/records in the inner class list
public Integer count = 1;
//{get;set;}


//add one more row
public void Add()
{   
    count = count+1;
    addMore();      
}

/*Begin addMore*/
public void addMore()
{
    //call to the iner class constructor
    innerClass objInnerClass = new innerClass(count);

    //add the record to the inner class list
    lstInner.add(objInnerClass);    
    system.debug('lstInner---->'+lstInner);            
}/* end addMore*/

/* begin delete */
public void Del()
{
    system.debug('selected row index---->'+selectedRowIndex);
    lstInner.remove(Integer.valueOf(selectedRowIndex)-1);
    count = count - 1;

}/*End del*/



/*Constructor*/
public MultiAdd(ApexPages.StandardController ctlr)
{
System.debug('clicked');
    lstInner = new List<innerClass>();
    addMore();
    selectedRowIndex = '0';

}/*End Constructor*/ 

  ////save the records by adding the elements in the inner class list to lstAcct,return to the same page
public PageReference saveCustom()
{
    System.debug('clicked');
    PageReference pr = new PageReference('/apex/MultiAdd');

    for(Integer j = 0;j<lstInner.size();j++)
    {
        lstAcct.add(lstInner[j].acct);

        System.debug(lstInner[j].acct.Condition__c);
    } 
    insert lstAcct;
    pr.setRedirect(True);
    return pr;
}

  ////save the records by adding the elements in the inner class list to lstAcct,return to the same page
public PageReference Save()
{
    System.debug('clicked');
    PageReference pr = new PageReference('/apex/MultiAdd');

    for(Integer j = 0;j<lstInner.size();j++)
    {
        lstAcct.add(lstInner[j].acct);

        System.debug(lstInner[j].acct.Condition__c);
    } 
    insert lstAcct;
    pr.setRedirect(True);
    return pr;
}    


/*Inner Class*/
public class innerClass
{       
    /*recCount acts as a index for a row. This will be helpful to identify the row to be deleted */
    public String recCount
    {get;set;}


    public SOQLQuery__c acct 
    {get;set;}

    /*Inner Class Constructor*/
    public innerClass(Integer intCount)
    {
        recCount = String.valueOf(intCount);        

        /*create a new SOQLQuery__c*/
        acct = new SOQLQuery__c();

    }/*End Inner class Constructor*/    
}/*End inner Class*/
}/*End Class*/
```

Comment: where is your save button?

Answer (score 0):

Everywhere you are using `pr.setRedirect(True);` this will aways disregard the page state and give you fresh page again. You should maintain the page state so use:

```
public PageReference Save()
{
    System.debug('clicked');
    PageReference pr = ApexPages.currentPage(); // redirect to same page with all params (if any)

    for(Integer j = 0;j<lstInner.size();j++)
    {
        lstAcct.add(lstInner[j].acct);

        System.debug(lstInner[j].acct.Condition__c);
    } 
    insert lstAcct;
    pr.setRedirect(false); // keeps the state.
    return pr;
}
```

However, it is not necessary to write `pr.setRedirect(false);` as `false` this is the default value.

Apply above approach to other methods. I assume that you have set `render` attributes correctly.